# Can I "reuse" a character in the next group of a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find occurrences of characters in a string if they appear before or after a certain "marker" character.

So my marker is `-` and the string is `"a b-c d"`. I want to find `b` and `c` in that order.

I tried

```
re.findall(r'(-[a-z]|[a-z]-)','a b-c d')
```

and obviously only get

```
['b-']
```

I also tried

```
re.findall(r'([a-z]-[a-z])','a b-c d')
```

and I get the result

```
['b-c']
```

, which is better, but I would still have to post-process this result in order to get the individual characters `b` and `c`.

Is there a one-step-solution to that problem?

**edit**

Follow-up problem: The string is `"a b-c-d e"` and I want to get something like `[('','a',''), ('','b','-'), ('-','c','-'), ('-','d',''), ('','e','')]`

I have a feeling that this is too much to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More groups.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(([a-z])-([a-z]))','a b-c d')
[('b-c', 'b', 'c')]
```

And since you don't actually care about the original...

```
>>> re.findall(r'([a-z])-([a-z])','a b-c d')
[('b', 'c')]
```

Comment: groups in groups. That was it!

Answer (score 2):

> The string is `"a b-c-d e"` and I want to get something like `[('','a',''), ('','b','-'), ('-','c','-'), ('-','d',''), ('','e','')]`

You may use

```
import re
s='a b-c-d e'
print (re.findall(r'(?=(-?)\b([a-z])\b(-?)).[^-]?', s))
# => [('', 'a', ''), ('', 'b', '-'), ('-', 'c', '-'), ('-', 'd', ''), ('', 'e', '')]
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cHuK2A/3) and [Python demos](https://ideone.com/GQ5qeF).

The problem here is that you want overlapping strings to get matched in different iterations, but skip certain positions if match occurs.

The main pattern is *optional hyphen* - *a whole word char* - *optional hyphen*. However, it should match and advance the regex index either to the next char, or to the next char after next char if it is not a hyphen (otherwise, you will get more results that expected).

**Details**

- `(?=(-?)\b([a-z])\b(-?)\b)` - a positive lookahead that does not consume text, and it matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `(-?)` - Group 1: an optional `-`
  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `([a-z])` - Group 2: a lowercase letter
  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `(-?)` - Group 3: an optional `-`
- `.` - any char other than newline
- `[^-]?` - 1 or 0 chars other than `-`.

Thanks to how `re.findall` works, the output only contains captured strings.